# How to call a function when user clicks Yes or No in ConfirmAlert Plugin of ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am using the ConfirmAlert plugin of ReactJs which provides the flexibility to choose what should happen when user clicks Yes or No on the confirm Dialog box. But when I click on Yes, i want a function to get invoked which performs some chunk of work. But the problem is that the function does not get called when I click "Yes". I dont know what mistake am I doing.

I can achieve this using window.confirm() method. But i want to make use of ConfirmAlert plugin provided by ReactJs.

```
  handleClick = (value) => {
            value.map(item => {
         if (item.props.status) {
                      confirmAlert({
                            title: "message",
                            message: "Are you sure?",
                            buttons: [
                                      {
                                        label: 'Yes',
                                        onclick: () => 

         (this.formCollection(item.props.name, item.props.id) // Does not Fire.
                                       },
                                       {
                                         label: 'No',
                                         onClick: () => window.alert("Subscription Aborted!!") // Works fine.
                                       } 
                                    ]
                                 })
                             }
                         })
                       }

               formCollection = (name, id) => {
                          // doing desired work here.
                         }


             <input type = "button" onclick={this.handleClick(alerts)} />
```

I expect the formCollection method to get triggerd when user clicks "Yes" on the confirm dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event name should be in camelCase

```
                buttons: [{
                label: 'Yes',
                onClick: () =>

                    this.formCollection(item.props.name, item.props.id) 
                    },
                {
                    label: 'No',
                    onClick: () => window.alert("Subscription Aborted!!") 
                }
            ]
```